# Black screen when opening a random camera app on Galaxy S7 Edge on LineageOS 18.1

Tags: camera, lineageos, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

Since last week I upgraded my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge from Samsung's stock firmware to LineageOS 18.1 by using [this message of the XDA forum](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-stable-signature-spoofing-microg-support-lineageos-18-1-for-s7-edge-exynos.4172727/) and installed the "full" edition of NicGApps. Since yesterday the camera does not always work, which is a behavior I never experienced on the stock Samsung firmware at all. When I open the camera app the screen is black. Also, when I change to the front facing camera. The only **temporary solution** is to reboot my device and everything works again.

During these two days, I rebooted my device three times, and that cannot be the intention. I tried this with several apps: OpenCamera, Footej Camera, the QR Code scanner of my banking app, all the same and as I wrote, after a reboot everything runs normal again. Does someone know a permanent solution?

Comment: When using an unofficial LineageOS version bugs like the one you describe can appear. Please report it in the XDA forum thread where you got the ROM from so that the ROM developer is aware of it and may be is able to fix it. Here we can do nothing to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I just posted the same question [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-stable-signature-spoofing-microg-support-lineageos-18-1-for-s7-edge-exynos.4172727/post-84744523)

Comment: Looks like you're not alone... [the post by Damjan94 on Mar 26](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-stable-signature-spoofing-microg-support-lineageos-18-1-for-s7-edge-exynos.4172727/post-84721471) also mentioned this: "*When videocalling with facebook, or discord, after 30 mins, or so, the camera stops responding, and both apps + provided camera app are only able to open a video stream for a second, before throwing an error that the camera couldn't be opened(discord and facebook just fail quietly)... a reboot fixes the camera, and it works fine for another 30 or so minutes.*"

Comment: ... and browsing back the thread, there were some more reports about the camera issues.

Comment: Thanks, I downgraded to Lineageos 17.1, as mentioned in the thread.

Comment: Did that fix the issues you were experiencing?

Comment: Yes, everything works stable now

Comment: Great! Thank you for the update!